# Django server doesn't launch

Tags: windows, python-3.x, django-1.6

I have a problem with starting django server. I'm trying use this russian tutorial: [Tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l_django/)to learn how to use python in web, but in the beginning they say i should open Django server with: python manage.py runserver. When i enter it, console opens for a one second and all i can see is: can't open file ‘manage.py’: No such file or directory.
What to do?
I use python 3.4 and django 1.6.4.`code`

Comment: Are you perhaps on Windows?  If you are, you should add the "windows" tag to this post, because you'll probably need help from another Windows user.  You'll need a shell in which to work, ideally one other than the default Windows shell -- does that tutorial recommend one?

Comment: No, doesn't recommend. I just use default python shell 3.4.0

Comment: The default Python shell for tinkering around in Python is fine; it sounds like it's the operating system shell that you're missing.  Powershell for Windows or bash via cygwin or another Windows UNIX layer will work.  I say this because if your console only opened for a second, that suggests you didn't run your command inside a shell but instead used the "run" dialog.

Comment: if i start program in powershell,it does nothing

Comment: i found answer: i started new project with 'python C:\Python34\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysites', then i entered python 'C:\Python34\mysite\manage.py runserver' instead of 'python manage.py runserver'